# How to achieve 'windows inversion' of mice properties for custom cursor color(s) customization?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I want to load a custom mouse cursor that will *invert* as it does for the Windows Inverted (System Scheme) to show the opposite of the colors in an area the cursor is occupying, hither, the "inverted" coloration of pixels; when loading another - custom - file the cursor does not reflect any inverted-color-behaviorism. Deliberately clicking the 'Mouse Pointer Style' in accessibility to **Inverted** will revert to the native default of an inverted system default cursor, nullifying the user's option of a custom cursor; am I indicated here that I have to make a change in the file itself or registry to accept cursor/file as invert-able?

I'm not finding as much information as I thought I would for such a minute subject as I'd suspected it related to shaders, blend modes, etc. so, I can only suspect that I as a user mustn't be allowed to customize the overuse of my hardware.

Comment: Are you making the cursor or the program? CUR is almost the same as ICO and supports inverted pixels.

Comment: Hi Anders thank you for engaging, I'm aiming to solely make the cursor

Comment: Then perhaps it is not a programming question? Just find a cursor editor...

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for unfortunately, I've tried the file formats approach (except for xcursor) and a trio of software: a plugin with Paint.Net, ArtCursors, and RealWorld Cursor Editor none have helped in the implementation of runtime cursor color inversion

Answer (score 0):

RealWorld Cursor Editor works. In the editor:

1. Create a new cursor, and change the file type to anything but the 32 bit color
   scheme (e.g. 24 bits - truecolor)
2. Change the color of the pencil to white and completely transparent (bottom right
   corner of triangle is white, bottom of the transparency bar is 100% clear)
3. Use the pencil in replace mode and draw your cursor. You can combine regular
   colors with the inverting color
4. Save the cursor somewhere
5. Go to "Mouse Settings" (press the Start button and type "mouse settings"). Click
   "Additional mouse options"
6. Go to "Pointers", and change the desired cursor to the new one

All information can be found on http://www.rw-designer.com/forum/1348